# Mouse selection of images with Psychopy

Tags: python-2.7, mouseevent, psychopy

I have created two stimuli(red and green rectangles) as stimuli in Psychopy. Also, I have enabled mouse movements to four directions. Using the function[mouse.getPressed()] in Psychopy for selecting the stimuli, I am facing some issues. 
Basically, I want the mouse to move in four directions, and when the mouse reaches red/green rectangle stimuli, I need to select that stimuli and change its color to blue.

Can anyone look into the issue and help me to resolve the same?

Here is my code:

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event 
import numpy as np


# Create a window.
# For configuring and debugging the code turn off full screen.
fullscr = False
win = visual.Window(
    [1200,1000],
    monitor="testMonitor",
    units="deg",
    fullscr=fullscr
    )

#cursor = visual.Circle(win, radius=0.2)

#cursor = visual.CustomMouse(win,
#    leftLimit=-10, topLimit=10, rightLimit=10, bottomLimit=-10,
#    showLimitBox=True, clickOnUp=True)

pos_zero = (0, 0)
cursor = visual.Rect(
        win=win, 
        size=400,
        pos=pos_zero,
        opacity=0
        )

mouse = event.Mouse(visible=True)


# Sinusoidal control version.
freq_one = 0.5
freq_two = 1.5
# Colors of the rectangles.
#color_zero='black'
color_one = 'red'
color_two = 'green'
# Positions of the rectanges.
pos_one = (-10, 0)
pos_two = (10, 0)


start = core.getTime()
cnt = 0
cursor.pos = mouse.getPos()
print cursor.pos
while cnt<600:
    second = core.getTime() - start

    sin_val_one = 0.5+0.5*np.sin(2 * np.pi * second * float(freq_one))
    sin_val_two = 0.5+0.5*np.sin(2 * np.pi * second * float(freq_two))

#while not mouse.getPressed()[0]:
    # Do something if mouse moved

    for key in event.getKeys():
        if key == 'escape': 
           core.quit()
        elif key == "right":
           cursor.pos = cursor.pos + (2,0)
        elif key =="left":
           cursor.pos = cursor.pos - (2,0) 
        elif key =="up":
           cursor.pos = cursor.pos + (0,2) 
        elif key =="down":
           cursor.pos = cursor.pos - (0,2) 


        #if cursor.pos == pos_one:
        #   mouse.getpressed(rect_one)
        #elif cursor.pos == pos_two:
        #   mouse.getpressed(rect_two)

    mouse.setPos(cursor.pos)  
    mouse.lastPos = cursor.pos  

    rect_one = visual.Rect(
        win=win,
        fillColor=color_one,
        lineColor=color_one, 
        size=15,
        pos=pos_one,
        opacity=sin_val_one
        )
    rect_two = visual.Rect(
        win=win,
        fillColor=color_two,
        lineColor=color_two, 
        size=15,
        pos=pos_two,
        opacity=sin_val_two
        )

#images = [rect_one, rect_two]

#for image in images:
#    if mouse.isPressedIn(image):
#        pressed_shape = shape
#            
#    pressed_image.fillColor = 'blue'
#    pressed_image.draw()
#    print pressed_image.name

    rect_one.draw()
    rect_two.draw()
    cursor.draw()
    win.flip()
    cnt += 1

win.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to change color on cursor overlap (`cursor_object.overlaps(rect_one)`) or on mouse press (`mouse.isPressedIn(rect_one)`)? And a more general question: why do you use the keyboard to control the mouse? If subjects are never going to use the mouse, then just move an image or so using the keyboard.

Comment: I want the color to change when the mouse reaches the image. It can be either one. I didn't know about the overlap function, so I thought of using mouse.isPressed. I am planning to integrate it with the brain signal acquisition board, where signals will be used for the mouse movement. But as far as now, I am making a prototype to test with Keyboard functions. I want the images to be selected when the cursor reaches there. This module is to integrate with a bigger module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made several changes and post the updated code below. It's significantly shorter and simpler.

- Removed everything using mouse. Since you just want something visual to move on key presses, there's no need to invoke the mouse - especially when you actually don't want subjects to use the mouse...
- Create the colored shapes once, then updating the color during runtime. This is significantly faster, i.e. avoids dropping frames.
- Changed the cursor size. It was 400 degrees!
- Removed the line around the rectangles so that only `fillColor` needs to be changed on overlap.
- A few other simplifications.

Here is the code:

```py
from psychopy import visual, core, event 
import numpy as np

# Settings
fullscr = False
directions = {'left': (-2,0), 'right': (2,0), 'up': (0, 2), 'down': (0, -2)}
freq_one = 0.5  # # Sinusoidal control
freq_two = 1.5

# Create a window.
win = visual.Window([1200,1000], monitor="testMonitor", units="deg", fullscr=fullscr)

# The two rectangles
rect_one = visual.Rect(win=win, fillColor='red', lineColor=None, size=15, pos=(-10, 0))
rect_two = visual.Rect(win=win, fillColor='green', lineColor=None, size=15, pos=(10, 0))

# Cursor
cursor = visual.Circle(win, fillColor='white', radius=0.2)

# Run five trials
for trial in range(5):
    # Set to initial condition
    rect_one.fillColor = 'red'
    rect_two.fillColor = 'green'
    cursor.pos = (0, 0)

    # Start task
    start = core.getTime()
    for frame in range(600):
        # Set rectangle opacities
        second = core.getTime() - start
        rect_one.opacity = 0.5+0.5*np.sin(2 * np.pi * second * float(freq_one))
        rect_two.opacity = 0.5+0.5*np.sin(2 * np.pi * second * float(freq_two))

        # Show it
        rect_one.draw()
        rect_two.draw()
        cursor.draw()
        win.flip()

        # Get keyboard responses and change color if there is overlap
        for key in event.getKeys():
            if key == 'escape': 
               core.quit()
            elif key in directions.keys():  # if this is a key corresponding to a direction
               cursor.pos += directions[key]   # Lookup the pos change in "directions" and add it to current position
               if cursor.overlaps(rect_one):
                   rect_one.fillColor = 'blue'
               if cursor.overlaps(rect_two):
                   rect_two.fillColor = 'blue'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code works perfect now. :) Also may I ask you a small doubt. Suppose if I want to continue the experiment, (that is after selecting images and making it blue-change to its initial states) should I remove the core.getTime() function and replace with a while loop?

Comment: I updated the code, putting a loop around everything so that it runs multiple trials. In the beginning it sets stuff to it's initial settings.

Comment: Please mark this response as accepted answer (and perhaps upvote) if it solves your problem.